# Is it possible to display an output with a scanner above the output?

Tags: java, output, java.util.scanner

I have a program here that includes only scanners and outputs. What I wanted the program to show is that to display a scanner with the output below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter anything: ");
     scan.nextLine();

    //while the scanner's text cursor shows, the bottom texts below also shows.

    System.out.println("bottom text");
    System.out.println("bottom text");      
    System.out.println("bottom text");
    System.out.println("bottom text");
    System.out.println("bottom text");
    System.out.println("bottom text");
    System.out.println("bottom text");



/*  what I wanted the output to show is this:

Enter anything: | << text cursor
bottom text
bottom text
bottom text
bottom text
bottom text
bottom text
bottom text



but the output shows like this instead:

Enter anything: |


*/      




}//end of method



}
```

Because it only shows the output below after the scanner has been used. Is it possible or is there any way to show the scanner and the bottom text at the same time? TIA :)

Comment: I think this should be possible with VT100 codes

Comment: @Sadap thanks for the tip, i researched it and it might be helpful regarding the display.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this...

CompletableFuture will spin off a new thread using `runAsync( () -> { return null; } )` you can also use `supplyAsync(() -> { returns anObject })` if you want to get a result from the thread. You can then chain additional threads which can be consumers/suppliers or a bit of both.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100); // delay start by 1/10 of a second.
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("bottom text");
            System.out.println("bottom text");
            System.out.println("bottom text");
            System.out.println("bottom text");
        });

        System.out.println("Enter anything: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You entered: " + input);
    }
```

Unfortunately when I put my cursor at the end of `Enter anything:` and the cursor went straight to the bottom so the output isn't quite what you're after...

```
Enter anything: 

bottom text
bottom text
bottom text
bottom text
something            <<<<<< My input here
You entered: something

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It I'm not 100% certain what you're trying to do is possible with such a simple set of commands. I'd imagine you'd need something more comprehensive to achieve what you're wanting.

Perhaps someone can improve on this?

Comment: Im sure it has to do something with user interfaces. I think any consoles display text cursors without an output below them unless a user prompts an input. Btw thanks for testing out my script :)